# Contributing to https://tug.org/ as a web developer

Tags: contribute

So, I am a web developer who loves minimalism and good typography. I was reading a bit on https://tug.org/ and after a few minutes of visiting different urls, I felt that I could contribute to the site.

I looked for links to github or where the sites are hosted and I couldn't find them. Is there a way to contribute to the sites themselves? I am comfortable with multiple version control systems, but just curious about contributing.

Comment: Maybe you should send a mail to webmaster@tug.org ?

Comment: you should ask there not here.  There really isn't any answer that can be given here.